# Is user code to rethrow an OperationCanceledException, caught from within its own try-catch

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

Recommended method of observing a cancellationToken cancellation request seems to be to  `ThrowIfCancellationRequested`.

But what happens if it is caught by user try-catch? From [MSDN's "How to: Cancel a Task and Its Children"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537607.aspx) with try-catch added to illustrate question:

```
snippet:

static void DoSomeWork(int taskNum, CancellationToken ct)
{
   try
   {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxIterations; i++)
        {
            // Do a bit of work. Not too much. 
            ...
            //ok not to do this check? most likely IsCancellationRequested does it already
            //if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            //{


                ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();


            //}
        }
    }
    catch(OperationCanceledException e1) // catching likely my own exception 
    {
       throw; // correct? anything else belongs here?
    }
    catch // ...
    {
        // do whatever else I might want to do here
    }
}
```

Am I fine re-throwing? I.e. I am not disturbing anything inside the Task APIs, am I?

(I will also express the personal opinion, that the point of an orderly cancel-cleanup-return seems at odds with exception being the vehicle for it; I assume there are other means to accomplish that - I'll keep digging)

Comment: I do this, it seems to work. Sometimes that is all you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rethrow should be fine. But usage of parameterless catch  is not recommended, as it swallows any exception info. You should use catch (Exception) and at least log these exceptions.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with the question itself.

Comment: @Matz, using catch without parameters is a Very Bad Practice, and someone could decide to copy the code from the question.